# wordpress can not find database, while mysql_client can

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysql-connection

I am trying to prepare a WordPress site, on my public web server, running apache2. The database host, I am trying to use, for the WordPress installation, is another server.

While I can successfully connect the db_host from my web server, through MySQL client, WordPress configuration can not connect the database.

[image]

Though mysql_client works from the same machine

[image]

Please help me

Comment: could you supply here error or log messages details, please

Comment: sorry. added now

Comment: What do you have as username in `wp-config.php`? Do you have there also the correct password?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think you must also [create a database](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/creating-database-for-wordpress/#using-the-mysql-client).